# Lower bounds for inner product $x^\top y$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Cauchy-Schwarz provides an upper bound for the inner product $x^\top y$. Are there theorems that talk about lower bounds for this quantity? Assume $x\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$ wlog.

Comment: $x^\top y \ge 0$ (positive-definiteness of inner product).  And this bound is tight, as you can have orthogonal vectors.

Comment: What do you mean by $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$?  Nonnegative components, with the vectors in $\mathbf{R}^n$?  If so, then, the lower bound is $0$.

Answer (score 9):

I assume by $x\geq 0$ and $y\geq 0$, you imply non-negative components. Define $a$ as the vector containing components of $x$ in the increasing (ascending) order and $b$ as the vector containing components of $y$ in the decreasing (descending) order, then $x^{T}y\geq a^{T}b$

Answer (score 5):

There are some theorems regarding lower bound on inner product. One of them is due to Kantorovich, $\Vert x \Vert \Vert y \Vert \le (\frac{A}{G}) x^T y$ for $x_i,y_i\gt 0$. Where $0\lt m\le \frac{x_i}{y_i} \le M \lt \infty$,  $A=(m+M)/2$ and $G=\sqrt (mM)$.

Comment: please cite the reference

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KantorovichInequality.html